# 3rd Party Windows Lockscreen app for quick breaks?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, lock-screen

I would like to unlock my machine quicker after a bathroom break, without changing my normal password-length.

For example, a 3rd party lock app that would require only a 2 character password or similar ... to be used during short absences from my computer.

Does not need to stop anyone with the slightest amount of skill, just random nosy people.

Win+L would retain its functionality, but some other shortcut key (win+B or something) would allow for a less secure lockscreen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Clear Lock](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Lockdown/ClearLock.shtml), you can set up a custom password and a AutoHot key script to trigger it based on what shortcut you want.

Comment: Thank you - this seems like what I was looking for, and more.

Comment: and more ?? What do ya mean ?

Comment: I mean that your solution is elegant. Tiny portable app that's easily configured via ini file, and allows for opacity control, either hiding my entire desktop or not, as a I see fit.

Comment: This was a good solution, but isn't compatible with multi-monitors, and seems to be fairly easy to override, so I'm now looking for other options.